# Passing permissions to perl's chmod and mkdir functions

Tags: perl

Here's something I don't understand.  In perl, let's say I have a file(handle) `$file` then

```
my $mode = (stat $file)[2];
```

gives the *mode* of the file, described as the type and permissions. Then, in the docs for [chmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html), it is recommended to mask off the file type when sending the mode from [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) to [chmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html) like, e.g.

```
my $perm = (stat $file)[2] & 07777;
chmod($perm | 0600, $file);
```

Similarly, the docs for [mkdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) indicate that `mkdir(FILENAME,MASK)` "creates the directory specified by `FILENAME`, with permissions specified by `MASK` (as modified by umask)."

Alrighty. Here's what I don't get. On the command line, I make a dir temp in my home directory, with default permissions drwxr-xr-x (octal 0755). Then

1. perl's stat tells me that the mode of this directory is 16877.
2. `$perms = (stat 'temp')[2] & 07777;` returns 493.
3. `$perms = sprintf("%04o",(stat 'temp')[2] & 07777);` returns 0755.

I expected `chmod(x,'temp')` with x = (1) and (2) to change the permissions on `temp/` to something screwy. But, all three give `drwxr-xr-x` (admittedly with (3) you must do `chmod(oct($perms),'temp);`) Similarly, `mkdir(temp,16877)`, `mkdir(temp,493)`, `mkdir(temp,0755)` all give permissions `drwxr-xr-x` on `temp/`.

So, my question: what's really going on? How is it that chmod and mkdir take these three different values and set the same permissions on `temp/`? I realize one answer might be 'there's more than one way to do it', and that's fine as far as it goes, but I'd like to understand what's happening here.  Also, what is the recommended way to pass permissions values to these functions? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot make sense of the phrase "chmod(x,'temp') with x = (1) and (2)". Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

493 decimal = 0755 octal, so this is a non issue - they are identical.
16877 decimal = 40755 octal.
Looks like chmod only uses the bits that it needs and ignores anything in the higher order bits.

Comment: Bits higher than 07777 will not be changed by `chmod` because the system protects sanity that way. For example, allowing a program to change S_IFDIR (04000) could change a regular file into a directory or vice versa; that would be Bad. Similarly S_IFBLK (060000) will only ever be set by `mknod(2)` and once a block device, always a block device so altering those bits would make no sense.

Comment: Thanks John3136 and msw - to clarify: the '& 07777' from the docs isn't necessary. Also, are there cases where mkdir and chmod handle this argument differently?

Comment: &07777 just makes sure you are only passing in 12 bits worth of flag. A sensible OS would ignore anything above 07777 anyway, but doing the AND is good programming practice. mkdir uses the mask provided as modified by the current umask. chmod would not use the cuirrent umask, so behaviour could be different.

Answer (score 2):

> Not all fields are supported on all filesystem types.  Here are
>   the meanings of the fields:

```
    0 dev      device number of filesystem
    1 ino      inode number
    2 mode     file mode  (type and permissions)
```

`(stat $file)[2]`, according to the docs, is the **file mode**, made up of **type** and permissions. 16877 decimal is 40755 octal. The extra 40000 is equivalent to `Fcntl::S_IFDIR`, telling you that `$file` is a directory.